# Removing/completely resetting inherited styles on img

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image, default, reset

I have an image that should stretch proportionally using only the HTML attributes. The default behaviour with no css set is that if the height attribute is set to half the natural height, then the width will automatically be half the natural width as well.

Example:

```
<img height="path/to/image.jpg" height="{half natural height}" />
```

The problem is that I am inheriting styles from an external library that i do not want to hack in that changes this behaviour.

I am trying to reverse the styles back to the browser default behaviour so that it would appear that the element has not been styled at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/23Hz4/2/

Failed attempts:

- Setting width: auto; height: auto does not work.  Setting width:
  initial; height: initial does not work.
- Setting element.style.width and element.style.height to null or empty strings does not work.
- delete element.style.width and delete element.style.width does not
  work

Any ideas?

Comment: Are CSS styles being inherited or is it only the actual height tag on the image element you're trying to overrule?

Comment: Try this: width: auto !important; height: auto !important; !important will override everything else and use new value.

Comment: I am trying to let the height-attribute of the image tag determine the  width of the image. The ratio should be the same as ratio between the natural width and height. I cannot change bootstrap, so I need to counter the styles that are inherited from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it works by using the `style` attribute instead of `height`

```
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" style="{height: half height};" />
```

The problem is the `height: auto;` css rule of bootstrap. The `height` attribute can't override this rule. So only a css rule can override this css rule.

Comment: I know - I am looking for a way to counter that rule.

Comment: downvoted for copy-pasting mistaken markup ... you mixed src  and  height just like OP. (just kidding)

Comment: Oops. A pretty bad copy/paste. Thanks.